# Creating dir in Python does not work (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with my python project. I startedd coding om my mac and later checked it out on my windows computer. The problem now is, that my method to create a file will not work (even so I adjusted it to the new file system).

What i try to do is create a subdirectory(C:\Users\t\Documents\pythonProject\SampleData\2016-10-19_16:03:57) in an existing directory(C:\Users\t\Documents\pythonProject\SampleData)

However when i execute the code i get an expection that says that the sytax of my filename is not right...

```
   def create_dir_if_not_exists():
       try:
           ts = time.time()
           st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
           Utils.folderTimerStamp = os.path.join('Users', 't', 'Documents', 'pythonProject', 'SampleData')
           Utils.folderName = 'SampleData\\' +st +'\\'

           if not os.path.exists(Utils.folderTimerStamp+"\\" +st  +"\\"):
               os.makedirs(Utils.folderTimerStamp+"\\" +st  +"\\")

       except OSError as exception:
           if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
               raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the drive letter `C:` and a `backslash` as your first parameter in your `os.path.join()` call:

```
os.path.join('C:\\','Users', 't', 'Documents', 'pythonProject', 'SampleData')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately it dod not work either.

Comment: Oh, the only problem is then that colons (:) are forbidden in Windows folder / files names, so you have change them (e. g. from 9:36:27 to 9-36-27)

Answer (score 1):

In windows

Folder names or filenames cannot contain any of these `\/:*?"<>|` characters.

So replace `:` any other character other than above

I  have replaced `:` to `-`

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```

Comment: Thanks! I also saw that after quiet some time. :D

Comment: @TorbenVerdorben If the answers helped to resolve your question then accept the answer .

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create file name, which is invalid accoring to [NTFS requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Exceprt from docs (**emphasis mine**):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), **except for the following**:
>
> - `<` (less than)
> - `>` (greater than)
> - **`:` (colon)**
> - `"` (double quote)
> - `/` (forward slash)
> - `\` (backslash)
> - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
> - `?` (question mark)

You need to change `st` value to represent valid NTFS filename, e.g.

```
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```

Comment: Thanks! I also saw that after quiet some time. :D